# Cannot preserve reference to array or readonly list, or list created from a non-default constructor

Tags: .net, serialization, json.net

I came across the below question which is mostly identical to the issue I am having:

[JSON.NET cannot handle simple array deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323397/json-net-cannot-handle-simple-array-deserialization)

However, my situation is slightly different.  If I modify the `Test` class from that question to have an array property of the same type, I get the same deserialization error.

```
class Test
{
    public Test[] Tests;
}

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All
};

var o = new Test { Tests = new[] { new Test(), new Test() } };
//var o = new Test(); //this works if I leave the Tests array property null
var arr = new[] { o, o };
var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr, settings);

arr = ((JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ser, settings)).ToObject<Test[]>();
```

I bet I am missing an important attribute on the `Tests` property.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Had to create a custom Json converter.  Will post results as answer as soon as I confirm the fix

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Json.NET simply hasn't implemented preserving of references for read-only collections and arrays.  This is explicitly stated in the exception message:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot preserve reference
> to array or readonly list, or list created from a non-default
> constructor: Question41293407.Test[].

The reason that Newtonsoft has not implemented this is that their reference tracking functionality is intended to be capable of preserving *recursive self references*.  Thus the object being deserialized must be allocated before reading its contents, so that nested back-references can be successfully resolved during content deserialization.  However, a read-only collection can only be allocated *after* its contents have been read, since by definition it is read-only.

Arrays, however, are peculiar in that they are only "semi" read-only: they cannot be resized after being allocated, however individual entries can be changed.  (see [Array.IsReadOnly inconsistent depending on interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765485/array-isreadonly-inconsistent-depending-on-interface-implementation) for a discussion about this.)  It's possible to take advantage of this fact to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for arrays that, during reading, loads the JSON into an intermediate `JToken`, allocates an array of the correct size by querying the token's contents, adds the array to the [`serializer.ReferenceResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_ReferenceResolver.htm), deserializes the contents into a list, then finally populates the array entries from the list:

```
public class ArrayReferencePreservngConverter : JsonConverter
{
    const string refProperty = "$ref";
    const string idProperty = "$id";
    const string valuesProperty = "$values";

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // byte [] is serialized as a Base64 string so incorporate fix by https://stackoverflow.com/users/13109224/dalecooper from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66177664
        if (objectType == typeof(byte[]))
            return false; // He would kill a Byte[] and you'll wonder, why the JSON Deserializer will return NULL on Byte[] :-)
        // Not implemented for multidimensional arrays.
        return objectType.IsArray && objectType.GetArrayRank() == 1;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Debug.Assert(CanConvert(objectType));
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            // No $ref.  Deserialize as a List<T> to avoid infinite recursion and return as an array.
            var elementType = objectType.GetElementType();
            var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
            var list = (IList)serializer.Deserialize(reader, listType);
            if (list == null)
                return null;
            var array = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, list.Count);
            list.CopyTo(array, 0);
            return array;
        }
        else
        {
            var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
            var refId = (string)obj[refProperty];
            if (refId != null)
            {
                var reference = serializer.ReferenceResolver.ResolveReference(serializer, refId);
                if (reference != null)
                    return reference;
            }
            var values = obj[valuesProperty];
            if (values == null || values.Type == JTokenType.Null)
                return null;
            if (!(values is JArray))
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("{0} was not an array", values));
            }
            var count = ((JArray)values).Count;

            var elementType = objectType.GetElementType();
            var array = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, count);

            var objId = (string)obj[idProperty];
            if (objId != null)
            {
                // Add the empty array into the reference table BEFORE poppulating it,
                // to handle recursive references.
                serializer.ReferenceResolver.AddReference(serializer, objId, array);
            }

            var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
            using (var subReader = values.CreateReader())
            {
                var list = (IList)serializer.Deserialize(subReader, listType);
                list.CopyTo(array, 0);
            }

            return array;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The memory efficiency of this approach is not great, so for large collections it would be better to switch to a `List<T>`.

Then use it like:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new ArrayReferencePreservngConverter() },
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All
};
var a2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test[]>(jsonString, settings);
```

Note the converter is completely generic and works for all single-dimensional arrays.  Multidimensional arrays are not implemented.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EuB1Th) showing successful deserialization of nested recursive self-references.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It ended up just using `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` because I realized that I really don't need a reference to an array itself, just the elements within the index.  After I changed it, it worked just fine.  I'll go ahead and mark yours as answer after a while here

Comment: The only issue with this is when you put an array inside of an object definition (compile-time) object. Then objectType.IsArray will not be true and the converter will not be executed.

Comment: There are a few improvements (not mine): https://localcoder.org/cannot-preserve-reference-to-array-or-readonly-list-or-list-created-from-a-non Unfortunately, it's still unreliable and crashes on complex graphs :(

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is nice but needs a refine

```
 var elementType = objectType.IsArray ? objectType.GetElementType() : objectType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

`objectType.IsGenericType` might be true so, we need to use `GetGenericArguments()[0]`

Comment: I don't understand when this would be necessary.  `CanConvert(Type objectType)` only returns `true` when `objectType.IsArray` so under what scenario would `objectType.IsArray` be `false` inside `ReadJson()`?

Answer (score 1):

if someone utilizes this converter, might be considering to modify this:

```
 public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
 {
        if (objectType == typeof(byte[]))
            return false; // He would kill a Byte[] and you'll wonder, why the JSON Deserializer will return NULL on Byte[] :-)

        return objectType.IsArray;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I incorporated your fix into my answer, with a link to your answer included.