# Call default JsonSerializer in a JsonConverter for certain value type arrays

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to achieve roughly what's described here:

[Recursively call JsonSerializer in a JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085805/recursively-call-jsonserializer-in-a-jsonconverter)

In short; To examine a value being deserialised, then either consume it in my own code, or hand it off the the default deserializer.

The example uses a nifty trick to avoid the same custom code being called recursively:

```
...
else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    // Use DummyDictionary to fool JsonSerializer into not using this converter recursively
    dictionary = serializer.Deserialize<DummyDictionary>(reader);
else
    dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
return dictionary;

/// <summary>
/// Dummy to fool JsonSerializer into not using this converter recursively
/// </summary>
private class DummyDictionary : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> { }
```

The `DummyDictionary` class acts as a proxy to control flow when Json.Net looks for a new deserializer.

I need to achieve the same for a `byte[]` instead of a Dictionary. If it's a string, I want to pass it off to the default handler. If an array of int, I'll handle myself.

Unfortunately, I can't implement a

```
private class DummyByteArray : byte[] { }
```

as byte is a value type and isn't an inheritable interface.

How can I achieve the control I need without changing every instance of a `byte[]` in my objects to `SomeNoddyByteProxy`?

Comment: json generally writes a byte[] as a base64 encoded string. So just read it as a string and do whatever you need with it?
I'm obviously missing something. Could you share a a bit more of what you're trying to do? A version of your current converter maybe?

Comment: if you're writing it as an array of numbers? ie `[1,2,3,4]` then read as array of int and down cast? Or as List<> (as dbc's answer). Or write a "while; read a byte; IEnumberable<byte> method; and ToArray() that.
All assuming you're writing it as a list of num. Is that what you're trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, as an aside, I note that Json.NET supports deserializing both an array of integers and a Base64 string to a `byte []` array natively.  I.e. the following unit test assertions both **just work**:

```
Assert.IsTrue(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte []>("[1, 2]")
              .SequenceEqual(new [] { (byte)1, (byte)2 }));
Assert.IsTrue(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte []>("\"AQI=\"")
              .SequenceEqual(new [] { (byte)1, (byte)2 }));
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nOjUmi).

That being said, there are a few options given in *[JSON.Net throws StackOverflowException when using [JsonConvert()]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29719509/3744182)* as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565387/3744182) to *[Newtonsoft Json.NET JsonConverter attribute preserve references issue when deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54550629/3744182)* for recursively calling the serializer to get a "default" deserialization:

1. If you don't need to pre-load the JSON into a `JToken` hierarchy, you can have the converter disable itself using a thread static member, and then call `serializer.Deserialize()` recursively.
2. If you do need to pre-load the JSON into a `JToken` hierarchy, you can embed the hierarchy inside a parent container and supersede and disable the converter using a dummy converter on the container's member.

An example converter using option #1 might look as follows:

```
public sealed class ByteConverter : JsonConverter<byte[]>
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static bool disabled;

    // Disables the converter in a thread-safe manner.
    bool Disabled { get { return disabled; } set { disabled = value; } }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return !Disabled; } }

    public override byte[] ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, byte[] existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType) // Skip past comments
        {
            case JsonToken.Null:
                return null;

            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                // Your custom logic here, e.g.:
                return serializer.Deserialize<List<byte>>(reader).ToArray();

            default:
                using (new PushValue<bool>(true, () => Disabled, val => Disabled = val))
                    return serializer.Deserialize<byte []>(reader);
        }
    }

    // Remainder omitted
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, byte[] value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public struct PushValue<T> : IDisposable
{
    Action<T> setValue;
    T oldValue;

    public PushValue(T value, Func<T> getValue, Action<T> setValue)
    {
        if (getValue == null || setValue == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.setValue = setValue;
        this.oldValue = getValue();
        setValue(value);
    }

    // By using a disposable struct we avoid the overhead of allocating and freeing an instance of a finalizable class.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (setValue != null)
            setValue(oldValue);
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TiKIHZ).

However, in your case things are simpler.  Json.NET considers a `byte []` array represented as a Base64 string to be a primitive, so you can simply load it into a `JToken` and use the [JToken Explicit Conversion (JToken toByte[])](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit_31.htm) operator to cast it to a `byte[]` array like so:

```
public class ByteConverter : JsonConverter<byte[]>
{
    public override byte[] ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, byte[] existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType) // Skip past comments
        {
            case JsonToken.Null:
                return null;

            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                // Your custom logic here, e.g.:
                return serializer.Deserialize<List<byte>>(reader).ToArray();

            default:
                return (byte[])JToken.Load(reader);
        }
    }

    // Remainder omitted
```

This entirely avoids use of the serializer.  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ciSM6r).