# Load objects with circular references to Blazor Wasm with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, blazor

#### Problem

I'm using Blazor WASM which communicates with RESTful API built with ASP.NET Core.
I need to load objects with circular references.

With default serialization settings, this produces System.Text.Json.JsonException:

```
A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger 
than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions 
to support cycles.
```

#### My attempt

I've added the following lines to ConfigureServices() in my Startup.cs on the server:

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => {
   options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
});
```

And modified the request on the client:

```cs
data = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<My.Shared.DataObject[]>(
    "api/GetDataObjects", 
    new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions() { 
        ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.Preserve
    }
);
```

When I run this, the server returns reasonable response:
[image: Response]

But the client throws System.Text.Json.JsonException when parsing the response:

```
Cannot parse a JSON object containing metadata properties like '$id' into an array or immutable 
collection type. Type 'My.Shared.DataObject[]'. 

Path: $.$id | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 7
```

**Why is this happening? How to fix it?**

Comment: Use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on the properties that create the circular reference. You can still let the foreign keys through of course just not the entity.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  But *Cannot parse a JSON object containing metadata properties like '$id' into an array or immutable collection type* seems explanatory.  As a guess, you have some collection type that you have declared as an array on the client side.  Try declaring it as a list instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory:

> Cannot parse a JSON object containing metadata properties like '$id' into an **array** or immutable
> collection type. **Type 'My.Shared.DataObject[]'**.

This confirmed by the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-5-0):

> For value types, immutable types, and arrays, no reference metadata is serialized. On deserialization, an exception is thrown if `$ref` or `$id` is found.

Instead of an array, you need to deserialize to a `List<DataObject>`:

```
data = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<My.Shared.DataObject>>(
    "api/GetDataObjects", 
    new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions() { 
        ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.Preserve
    }
);
```

Notes:

- The restriction was likely implemented because arrays and read-only collections can only be fully constructed after their items are read in - but `ReferenceHandler` is intented to support back-references from children to parents as well as recursive self-references from the object to itself.  And it's unclear how to implement such functionality for read-only collections or immutable objects that can only be constructed after their child items are constructed.

  Json.NET has a similar restriction, see *[Cannot preserve reference to array or readonly list, or list created from a non-default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41293407/3744182)* for details.
- If you do not need reference preservation for collections, you can serialize your collection as an array and `$id` information will not be included for the array itself. (Its items will still contain the required `$id` properties.)

  I.e. on your server side, you must be sending a `List<My.Shared.DataObject>` over the wire.  If instead you send a `My.Shared.DataObject []` the root container will be a simple JSON array, not a JSON object with reference information and a nested `$values` array.

  For comparison, whereas Json.NET supports preserving references only for objects and not collections by setting [`PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_PreserveReferencesHandling.htm), System.Text.Json does not appear to provide this level of control via options.
- You can always convert the `List<DataObject>` to an array afterwards with [`ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=net-5.0).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PA70tO).